# What is the access log path for .net core(2.2) web application deployed as Windows Service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-7.5, iis-express, asp.net-core-2.2

I have deployed my `.net core(2.2)` Web Application as windows service and I want to check the access log for the same.

If any application is publish on `IIS server` (Windows) then access log is written at below path.

Path: `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1`

In similar way what will be the path for access log for  `.net core(2.2)` Web Application running as a windows service.

Is their any handling is required inside code to write access log?

Answer (score 0):

By default, ASP.NET Core logs to the console. When running in IIS, the Console output will be redirected to the logfile configured in `web.config`.

On every other hosting model you have to handle log persistence yourself with the use of a 3rd party framework (preferably one which integrates in ASP.NET Cores logging abstraction layer).

ASP.NET Core doesn't ship with it's own file-based logger. However, when hosting on Windows you can use the "EventSource" logger (its registered by default starting with ASP.NET Core 2.2 when using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` in

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

A list of Microsoft provided logging provides can be seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/release/2.2/src/Logging), for everything else you need to use 3rd party library, i.e. NLog etc.

A list of 3rd party logging libraries supporting .NET Core's logging abstractions is included in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#third-party-logging-providers).

> - [elmah.io](https://elmah.io/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.Extensions.Logging))
> - [Gelf](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/gelf.html) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/mattwcole/gelf-extensions-logging))
> - [JSNLog](http://jsnlog.com/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/mperdeck/jsnlog))
> - [KissLog.net](https://kisslog.net/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/catalingavan/KissLog-net))
> - [Loggr](http://loggr.net/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/imobile3/Loggr.Extensions.Logging))
> - [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging))
> - [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet))
> - [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging))
> - [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/stackdriver#logging) ([Github repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet))

Comment: I have written the application level log(Info, Warn, Error) inside application but I want to know about Access log.(Same As IIS log) Format: #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

Comment: Dunno about that, access logs are usually done by webservers, however windows service or kestrel aren't strictly webservers, just application hosts. At a high enough level (information) the ASP.NET Cores logger prints request information too, but it doesnt have useragent, ip and the other stuff in it

Answer (score 0):

Kestrel doesn't currently support the W3C format, or the IIS extended format options when logging (you can track this feature [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5894)), so when running ASP.NET Core as a Windows Service, you'll (for now) need to rely on using one of the logging packages (Console, EventSource, etc.).

Alternatively, an external logging tool, such as Sentry would work well - obviously, there is a cost associated with many of these services. We use Sentry over Elmah these days as it has wider platforms support, including non-.NET technologies, such as JavaScript, etc.

Comment: It means by default access log is not written for ASP.NET core Web application as a Windows Service. For access log we need to use any Third Party logging tool & need to write log as par requirement.